# how to inherit STL container w/o allowing user to use base class pointer?

Tags: c++, inheritance, stl

Hi I want to inherit from a STL container (set), according to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14089088/are-stl-containers-designed-to-allow-inheritance):

> If you need inheritance for dynamic polymorphism standard library container classes are not designed for it, but If you don't need that you can safely inherit from them.

So my question is: how can I inherit an STL container (inherited by say, A) while ensuring that the user of class A will not be able to assign the pointer to an A object to its base class pointer?

Comment: Why would you want to inherit then in the first place?

Comment: Use private inheritance. `class A : private std::vector<int>`. The usefulness of this is questionable, though. It would be simpler to compose.

Comment: @GManNickG then he can not use methods, and I guess that is why he wants this

Comment: @BЈовић: Of course he can, and if he wants his new class to provide them too, he can just wrap it.

Comment: @BЈовић they can provide public access to the methods methods they want via `using` declarations.

Comment: Depending on what you want to achieve, I think using the delegation pattern might be something to keep in mind, instead of inheritance. Having a private vector member would allow you to control exactly what interface you want to expose to your class' clients.

Comment: @juanchopanza Yes, and I would call it a bad class with 50 using in it.

Comment: @BЈовић it doesn't have to have so many of them. I am not saying it is a good idea either, but private inheritance doesn't mean that "he cannot use methods".

Comment: I don't know of any mechanism in c++ than can prohibit the use of a base class pointer pointing to a derived class object. Isn't that the point of the question? Some one educate me if I'm wrong. We should be worried about proper destruction ...right?

Comment: @Rich private inheritance can do this, you can't do A* obj = new B; if B is privately inherited from A. But I think it would be better to know why the OP wants to inherit an STL container first, there might be better way to design this.