# What is the way to inherit std::string right?

Tags: c++, string, class, inheritance

Recently, I have been wanting to define a subclass spstring of std::string. It declared in spstr.h:

```
#include <cctype>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <xstring>


class spstring : public std::string {
public:
    spstring(std::string s):std::string(s){}  //Declare the constructor
    int stoi(); //Declare stoi
    spstring Spstring(std::string s); ////Declare mandatory conversion function
};

spstring spstring::Spstring(std::string s)
{
    spstring spstr(s); 
    return(spstr);
}
```

However, when tested in main.cpp:

```
spstring byteaddstr(std::string(argv[4])); //convertchar* to spstring
int byteadd;
byteadd=byteaddstr.stoi(); //call byteaddstr.stoi
```

it failed to be complied for:

> error C2228: left of “.stoi” must have class/struct/union

Sounds strange, since byteaddstr indeed an instance of spstring, why cannot call its member function?

Comment: You generally don't want to derive from STL containers.

Comment: In general, it is considered a bad idea to inherit from `std::string`, especially publicly [(see related SO post)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006860/why-should-one-not-derive-from-c-std-string-class). Private inheritance *might* be considered safe enough, although it still imposes a tight coupling between your class and `std::string`. See an interesting discussion on [abuses of inheritance here](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill06.htm). As for the error, please post a short, self-contained example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: You don't derive from std::string (or map, or vector, or any other container). In all instances where I encountered this there were several better solutions available.
Whenever you need to derive from an stl container, consider encapsulation instead, meaning either using the container as a member of your class, or using private inheritance.

Comment: Note that passing std::string by value is inefficient, use const reference or move syntax instead.

Comment: With regards to using STL containers to define new types, composition is the best approach than inheritance. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14089088/are-stl-containers-designed-to-allow-inheritance

Comment: @Popopo: See this question to get some perspectives on why composition is preferred to inheritance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++ any declaration that *can* be parsed as a function declaration, such as …

```
    spstring byteaddstr(std::string(argv[4])); //convertchar* to spstring
```

*is* parsed as a function declaration.

I.e. not a variable.

One solution in this particular case, is to add extra parentheses:

```
    spstring byteaddstr(( std::string(argv[4]) )); //convertchar* to spstring
```

This is known as the **most vexing parse** in C++, although some people disagree about whether Scott Meyers' original use of that term applies as generally as it's used now.

---

And by the way, one should generally have a pretty good reason to *derive* from `std::string`, because it adds complexity and confusion (you can safely disregard concerns about dynamic allocation, because code that dynamically allocates `std::string` deserves whatever it gets). So, I suggest that you don't do that.

Comment: Yes, this is the buttom line. Thanks a lot!

Comment: So, what exactly are problems regarding the inheritance, if we disregard concerns about dynamic allocation?  My understanding is that inheritance makes the code more complex and harder to understand. Is there more to it?

Comment: @BЈовић: not really, imo. but those properties translate to *more work*.

Answer (score 1):

Inheriting from `std::string` (and the STL containers) is a bad idea. They are not designed to operate as base classes.

Importantly, they don't necessarily have a virtual destructor so that can make memory management difficult for derived classes.

You would also lose readability too: If I see an STL class or function then I know exactly what is going to happen as it's assumed that I've memorised the standard. With a derived class I have to rely on its documentation or program comments.

So my answer: **There is no right way to inherit from std::string**.