# Before Virtual destructor concept, all programs had memory leak?

Tags: c++11, virtual, destructor

I was thinking when there was no concept of `virtual destructor` then all programs developed during that time had `memory leak` issues or they were using other concept to avoid memory leak?

Comment: What set of programs or time period are you considering?  Even today there are classes which purposefully do not use virtual destructors, [the standard library collections (and prior to that the STL) do not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647298/why-dont-stl-containers-have-virtual-destructors).  And there are still people using C doing *fully* manual memory management; and C++ always had virtual destructors.  You have to narrow/focus your question and do a bit of reading, to make something besides *"I was thinking..."*.  Please see [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks HostileFork for links!

Comment: You're welcome; and I encourage you to remain persistent even with downvotes or having questions put on hold.  I learned most everything I know about the advances in C++11 from participating in StackOverflow, over the course of a couple of years.  You can learn quickly even just by reading [highly upvoted Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b?sort=votes&pageSize=50).  Read as many as you can!  Try answering "easy" questions and sometimes not as easy as you think...there may be much better answers showing up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, in general past programs without virtual destructor did not have memory leaks. Talking on C++ virtual destructors were invented at about the same time as other virtual functions and inherritance mechanics so it was somewhat diesigned with virtual destructors builtin.

Those desctructors needed and explicit `virtual` keyword though.