# Can I subclass std::string in order to add a few extra members/flags?

Tags: c++, stl, polymorphism

I have the following struct:

```
struct A {
  std::string data;
  bool flag;
};
```

I want users of my class to be able to use it like a string in most cases. This means the `==` operator, iterators, `[]` indexing, etc. I'd have to write a bunch delegating methods for that. But instead I could do this:

```
struct A : std::string {
  using std::string::string; // Bring in all constructors.
  bool flag;
};
```

Does this have any downsides?

Comment: Do you use dynamic polymorphism? If yes, I am not sure that std::string have a virtual destructor :/

Comment: What's the purpose of the flag? Is it used to indicate whether the underlying string is valid or not? According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/1647316/12160191 STL containers are not designed to be inherited from.

Comment: The flag is metadata (i.e. some information about the contents of the string). I suppose composition is the better way to go here.