# How can I multiply a map with operator overloading?

Tags: c++, dictionary

I making a custom map class (`kc::map`) that extends `std::map`, and I want to add `operator*`. `operator+`/`operator+=` works, but `operator*` doesn't works:

```
template<typename K, typename V> class map : public std::map<K, V>
{
    public:
        using std::map<K, V>::map;
        map<K, V> get_value()
        {
            return *this;
        }
        map<K, V> operator+(map<K, V> m)
        {
            map<K, V> output = get_value();
            output.insert(m.begin(), m.end());
            return output;
        }
        map<K, V> operator*(int x)
        {
            map<K, V> md = get_value();
            map<K, V> output = md;
            for (int i = 0; i < x - 1; i++)
            {
                output += md;
            }
            return output;
        }
        map<K, V> operator+=(map<K, V> m)
        {
            *this = *this + m;
            return *this;
        }
        map<K, V> operator*=(int x)
        {
            *this = *this * x;
            return *this;
        }
};
```

**Edit**

Actually, the problem is in `operator+`. Actually, I tested `operator+` in the one-element case.

Comment: First of all I wouldn't make this operations in a derived map (inheritance from stl type isn't recommended anyway), but standalone functions. I also would not pass x as int, but as const T& (so you multiply values in the map with an x of their own type). The get_values is not necessary and in operator* you should iterate over key,value pairs and only update the values (have a look at structured bindings to do this nicely)

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Fails to compile? If so, what's the error message? Compiles but produces unexpected output? If so please edit the question to include a minimal reproducible example demonstrating the calling code and what you expected to happen instead.

Comment: One of the (multiple) problems with your code is that you pass your map by value. I guess that is not what you intended to do.

Comment: This is a link to a question about STL and inheritance, you might find it interesting : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647298/why-dont-stl-containers-have-virtual-destructors

Comment: Are inserting a map into itself when "multiplying", i.e. map the same same keys to the same values again and again? It works, you just can't notice any difference.

Comment: Your `+` ignores keys that are common in `this` and `m`. I'm wouldn't call that `operator +`, I'd call it `intersection`, or `operator |`. Because of that your `*` is a long-winded way of copying.

Comment: Offtopic: `I making a custom map class (kc::map) that extends std::map` - don't do that! I know that beginners believes that OOP is about inheriting after everything, but this bad approach. Try use map as filed of your class, it may look like more work, but you will avoid lots of strange problems. Please describe what your class suppose to be used for, then we will provide more detailed and solid reasons to drop this inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

Example for multiplication :

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

template<typename key_t, typename value_t>
auto operator*(std::map<key_t, value_t> copy_of_map, const value_t& factor)
{
    for (auto& [key, value] : copy_of_map)         // range based for loop, loops over all key/value pairs (the [key,value] is a structured binding)
    {
        value *= factor;                    // value is reference so we can change it.
    }

    return copy_of_map;
}


int main()
{
    std::map<int, int> map{ {1,1},{2,2},{3,3},{4,4} };
    auto multiplied_map = (map * 4);

    for (const auto& [key, value] : multiplied_map)
    {
        std::cout << "key = " << key << ", value = " << value << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you please implement `operator*`?

Comment: I updated the example to use operator* instead of making it a named function. But I still strongly advise you not to inherit from std::map

Comment: Oh, OK, thanks; let me test it

Comment: Wait, this isn't what I want. I don't want to return `auto`, I want to return `map<K, V>` if possible.

Comment: It will do exactly that :) It will return a std::map<key_t,value_t> I just let the compiler figure that out for me. (https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/type-deduction-for-objects-using-the-auto-keyword/).

Comment: Oh, but you returned `auto`

Comment: Also, I edited my question, to make the codes better

Comment: auto means let the compiler figure out the type and return that. Personally I think it leads to cleaner looking code and is easier to refactor.

Answer (score 0):

You need a sensible `+`.

If I were "adding maps" I'd want a value for each key in the intersection, adding the values that have intersecting keys.

```
map<K, V> operator+(map<K, V> m) const
{
    for (const auto & [key, value] : *this) {
        m[key] += value;
    }
    return m;
}
```

Whilst you can write `*` in terms of repeated addition, I wouldn't. That also allows you to multiply by `V`, not `int`.

```
map<K, V> operator*(V x)
{
    map<K, V> output = *this;
    for (auto & value : output | std::ranges::views::values) {
        value *= x;
    }
    return output;
}
```