# How can I return `map<K, V>::iterator`? (`map` class extends `std::map`)

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator

I making a custom map class (`kc::map`) that extends `std::map`, and I want to add `at_index()`, and I need to return `map<K, V>::iterator`. But when I return `map<K, V>`, this error occurs: `error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class kc::map<K, V>’`:

```
namespace kc
{
    template<typename K, typename V> class map : public std::map<K, V>
    {
        public:
            using std::map<K, V>::map;
            map<K, V> get_value()
            {
                return *this;
            }
            map<K, V>::iterator at_index(int index)
            {
                map<K, V> m = get_value();
                for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
                {
                    m.erase(m.begin());
                }
                return m.begin();
            }
    };
};
```

Comment: Do you want it to return `kc::map<K, V>::iterator` (which doesn't exist in your shown code) or do you want it to return `std::map<K, V>::iterator`? And you should probably ask yourself the same for the other mentions of `map<K, V>` in your code as well.

Comment: Deriving from standard classes is rarely a good idea. Even if you get this to compile you're returning an iterator to a local map which will cease to exist at the end of the function

Comment: https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2018/12/11/dont-inherit-from-std-types

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034916/is-it-okay-to-inherit-implementation-from-stl-containers-rather-than-delegate

Comment: Your `at_index` function returns an iterator to a **copy** of the map that has already been destructed by the time the function returns the iterator to the caller.

Comment: the standard library offers different customization points for working with containers. Inheriting from them isnt one of them. I dont quite understand what the code does, but it seems it could be an alogrithm  taking two iterators and returning one

Comment: See you really shouldn't inherit from STL (as I already mentioned in your previous question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70751096/how-can-i-multiply-a-map-with-operator-overloading/70751202)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring the real problems with the code (deriving from standard containers is not recommended and `at_index` returns a dangling iterator to the local object `m`) to get the code to compile you have two options.

1. within a class you don't need to prefix members of the class with the class name. As `iterator` isn't a class member you need to add it first then an unqualified `iterator` will work:

```
using iterator = typename std::map<K, V>::iterator;
iterator at_index(int index)
```

2. You can just use `std::map::iterator` directly:

```
typename std::map<K, V>::iterator at_index(int index)
```

If what you're actually trying to do is get the ith item in a `std::map` this will work:

```
#include <map>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>

namespace kc
{
    template<typename K, typename V> class map
    {
        private:
            std::map<K, V> impl;

        public:
            using iterator = typename std::map<K, V>::iterator;
            using value_type = typename std::map<K, V>::value_type;

            std::pair<iterator, bool> insert( const value_type& value )
            {
                return impl.insert(value);
            }
           
            iterator at_index(int index)
            {
                if (index >= impl.size())
                {
                    throw std::invalid_argument("index out of range");
                }
                auto it = impl.begin();
                std::advance(it, index);
                return it;
            }
    };
};

int main()
{
    kc::map<int, int> m;
    m.insert({1, 1});
    m.insert({2, 2});
    m.insert({3, 3});
    std::cout << m.at_index(2)->second;
}
```

Comment: Isn't that possible to return `kc::map<K, V>` instead of `std::map<K, V>`?

Comment: @NoIdeaForUsername from where?

Comment: Thanks, just used `typename map<K, V>::iterator` instead of `map<K, V>::iterator`, and it works! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could return a `std::map<K,V>::iterator`. This would make your code compile, but the iterator would be invalid. `get_value` returns a copy, `m` is local to `at_index` and gets destroyed when the function returns.

Inheriting publicly from standard containers is rarely a good idea. Standard containers are not made to be inherited from (eg they do not have a virtual destructor). You can write `at_index` as an algorithm:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

template <typename IT>
IT get_at_index(IT begin,IT end,unsigned index){
    if (std::distance(begin,end) < index) return end;
    return std::next(begin,index);
}


int main() {
    std::map<int,int> m{{1,1},{2,2},{3,3}};
    auto it = get_at_index(m.begin(),m.end(),1);
    if (it != m.end()) std::cout << it->first << " " << it->second << "\n";

    it = get_at_index(m.begin(),m.end(),5);
    if (it == m.end()) std::cout << "index 5 is out of range\n";
}
```

However, a `std::map` isnt meant to be accessed by index. It is rather expensive to advance a maps iterator. If you want a container of key-value pairs that you can access by index, consider to use a `std::vector<std::pair<K,V>>` instead.

Comment: note that `std::map<K,V>::iterator` needs a `typename` as it's a template dependant type